# Elegant and Efficient way to map dates from one dataframe to another - Big data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have two dataframes as given below

```
t1 = pd.DataFrame({'person_id':[1,2,3],'observation_date':[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],'observation_datetime':[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]})

t2 = pd.DataFrame({'person_id':[1,2,3],'value_as_string':['5/28/2007','5/30/2007','6/4/2007']}).set_index('person_id')['value_as_string']
```

They look like as shown below

[image]

This is what I tried to get the output

```
t1['observation_date'] = t1['person_id'].map(t2)
t1['observation_date'] = pd.to_datetime(t1['observation_date'])
t1['observation_datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(t1['observation_date']).dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

Though this works fine, it takes lot of time in real data

Please note that I am trying to do this on `t1` dataframe of size **1 million** records and `t2` dataframe of size of **15k** records. So any efficient approach would be helpful

I expect my output dataframe to look like as shown below

[image]

Comment: Actual issue was about mentioning the format for `pd.to_datetime`, that reduced the time. As @Mohsin answer talked about format, I am marking it as a solution. I have also given an upvote for the rest of the answers as well as it was useful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ids = list(range(1, 15000))
dte = ['5/28/2007','5/30/2007','6/4/2007'] * 5000
t1 = pd.DataFrame({'person_id': ids})
t2 = pd.DataFrame({'person_id': ids, 
                   'value_as_string': dte)
```

Merge approach

```
x = t1.merge(t2, how='left', on='person_id', how='left')
# 5.19 ms ± 408 µs per loop
```

Join approach

```
x = t1.set_index('person_id').join(df2.set_index('person_id'), how='left') 
# 3.02 ms ± 91.4 µs per loop
```

Map approach with dict

```
t1['observation_date'] = t1['person_id'].map(
       t2.set_index('person_id')['value_as_string'].to_dict())
# 2.73 ms ± 240 µs per loop
```

Map approach without dict

```
t1['observation_date'] = t1['person_id'].map(t2.set_index('person_id')['value_as_string'])
# 2.33 ms ± 260 µs per loop
```

So

```
t1['observation_date'] = pd.to_datetime(
        t1['person_id'].map(t2.set_index('person_id')['value_as_string']))
t1['observation_datetime'] = t1['observation_date'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: Do we have to convert it as dict? for the map approach?

Comment: This solved a problem I've been on for 3 days.

Answer (score 1):

I have a workaround for your problem. Instead of mapping, why don't you use a faster approach like a merge in pandas? I have used it on records ranging in close to a million and it is surprisingly fast.

The process of merging begins with two dataframes. Try doing

```
df =  t1.merge(t2, on = 'person_id', how='inner')
```

this would do an inner join on person_id on both columns in both dataframes(t1 and t2). You would get a new column introduced in resultant dataframe. You can then use simple column manipulation to fill the value in the target column.

Hope that helped.

Comment: Sure, Tell me if any issue comes with this approach @SSMK

Comment: I have used pd.merge on very large dataset and it did not take more that 2 seconds. I believe that's pretty fast given the number of records. I can't compare it with map, for i haven't used map on a dataframe. But OP says it is slow, let's hear the verdict from him.

Comment: ok, agree, it depends. From my info map is faster, but it depends of number of rows, number of unique values of dict...

Comment: @jezrael - There can be duplicates in my t2. Each person can have the same observation date. However, as I am using person_id (which is unique - 15k records) to match, will this affect map operation?

Comment: @jezrael , You use set_index after dataframes, Please explain why and when they can are used? Sorry my reputation is low so i can't comment on your answer.

Comment: `You use set_index after dataframes` - where?

Comment: In the sample dataframe above `t2`, instead having it as two seperate lines, I used them in same line while df creation which finally becomes as a series

Comment: @Heathcliff - With merge appraoch, I get a new(resultant extra) column in t1 but again the manipulation to the required column (`observation_date` and `observation_datetime` takes a bit of time

Comment: @jezrael Here t2.set_index('person_id')

Comment: @SSMK You can rename the newly added column as observation_date and change dtype of this column and store it in df['observation_datetime'] as a new column. What approach did you use...

Comment: @Heathcliff - It was about including the `format` parameter in map code

Answer (score 1):

Converting to datetime format takes a lot of time as well, you can speed that up by explicitly specifying datetime format as an argument to `pd.to_datetime`. It can give up to 10x improvement for you case.

Simulating your case.

```
import pandas as pd

t1 = pd.DataFrame({'person_id':[i for i in range(1000000)],'observation_date':[np.nan]*1000000,'observation_datetime':[np.nan]*1000000})
t2 = pd.DataFrame({'person_id':np.random.choice(1000000, replace=False, size=15000),
                   'value_as_string':['5/28/2007','5/30/2007','6/4/2007']*5000}).set_index('person_id')['value_as_string']


def map_infere_datetime_format(t1, t2):
  t1['observation_date'] = t1['person_id'].map(t2)
  t1['observation_date'] = pd.to_datetime(t1['observation_date'])
  t1['observation_datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(t1['observation_date']).dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
  return t1

# explicitly specify format instead of pandas doing the work for you
def map_explicit_datetime_format(t1, t2):
  t1['observation_date'] = t1['person_id'].map(t2)
  t1['observation_date'] = pd.to_datetime(t1['observation_date'], format='%m/%d/%Y')
  t1['observation_datetime'] = t1['observation_date'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
  return t1
```

Test results running on google colab:

```
%%timeit -n3
map_infere_datetime_format(t1, t2)
# 3 loops, best of 3: 2.04 s per loop

%%timeit -n3
map_explicit_datetime_format(t1, t2)
# 3 loops, best of 3: 290 ms per loop
```

Since, t2 is small it would make sense to convert t2 to datetime before mapping for a small speedup.

Hope it helps!

Comment: But @Mohsin hasan - a quick question. when I use the format in your code, I don't get the `%H:%M:%S`' component in my date value. Moreover when I use the format as '%m/%d/%Y', I get the output as `2007-05-28`.

Comment: Edited the answer! But I think there is some confusion here with respect to understanding of datetime object. When you use `pd.to_datetime` it converts string to datetime object with nano second resolution. Don't get tricked by print display of datetime object! since all h,m,s values are same, it only shows date. If you want a column with only date, then you can use `.dt.date` accessor to get that.

Comment: What I am trying to understand is `pd.to_datetime(t1['observation_date'], format='%m/%d/%Y'`, this line of code returns output as `2007-08-24`. Shouldn't it be `08/24/2007` as per the format(`%m/%d/%Y`)

Comment: That is string representation of your datetime object in pandas. You can use [`.dt.strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) to change string representation of your datetime object.

Comment: On the other hand, `format` tells pandas parser what the format of input string is like. You can refer to documentation here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html#pandas.to_datetime for more detailed explanation and examples